# Adding break every 2 consecutive floated elements (nth:child)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this fiddle so that you can see what i am trying to do easily.
I would like to add that break after every 2 consecutive div elements (div.column)

Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5qS5/

I tried:

```
$(".column:nth-child(2)").after('<br /><br />break<br /><br />');
```

It seems to work after the 2nd child only, how can I make it consecutive and works for every 2 elements afterwards.. I hope it's simple :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need `2n` instead of `2`, like this:

```
$(".column:nth-child(2n)").after('<br /><br />break<br /><br />');
```

[You can view the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/j5qS5/1/).

Comment: in this particular example, the `:odd` pseudo should also work quite well.

Comment: @jAndy - true, though for a column layout I think this is much more flexible and clearer as to what's going on (especially given jQuery's `:odd` and `:even` selectors are counter-intuitive)...this uses native selectors that work in CSS as well, so you can be consistent :)